# How to display a block only on certain page view display

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

What is the snippet of code to make a block just show in pages generated by a certain View?

[image]

Using Drupal 6 with Views 2.

Comment: Can you not just put the paths of the View pages into the "Show on only the listed pages" box? Or do you need something dynamic?

Comment: Thing is the path is both for views and nodes: `/foo/list` is View, `/foo/list/node` is node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`views_get_page_view()`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_get_page_view) to retrieve the view currently in use.

```
<?php
  $display = views_get_page_view();
  $view = $display->view;
  return !empty($view) && $view->name == 'Foo';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 7 this works:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_page_view();
  return isset($view) && $view->name == 'Foo';
?>
```